# Importing jscolor library in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

Im trying to get the JScolor library to work on my angular 2 site. Im fairly new so I dont have a clue what the problem is.

In my component I import the library like:

```
Import 'the/path/to/the/library';
```

And I give the html element the class jscolor so the library knows on which element it should work.

Is this just never gonna work since angular 2 framework just doesnt work like this or do I forget something?

Comment: do you get any error? do you see the JScolor  file loaded in the network tab? I'm guessing you need to add it to SystemJS

Comment: Yes it gets loaded and no errors. Im trying rinukkusu's solution now!

Answer (score 0):

In your `index.html` add a script tag to load the `jscolor.js`:

```
<script src='the/path/to/the/library'></script>
```

I generated a type defintion file for TypeScript which should basically work here: https://gist.github.com/rinukkusu/63ae4530561c89a95c9c3d716c0a7b3b

```
declare var jscolor: {
    dir: string;
    binding: boolean;
    preloading: boolean;
    install: () => void;
    init: () => void;
    getDir: () => any;
    detectDir: () => any;
    bind: () => void;
    preload: () => void;
    images: {
        pad: number[];
        sld: number[];
        cross: number[];
        arrow: number[];
    };
    imgRequire: {};
    imgLoaded: {};
    requireImage: (filename: any) => void;
    loadImage: (filename: any) => void;
    fetchElement: (mixed: any) => any;
    addEvent: (el: any, evnt: any, func: any) => void;
    fireEvent: (el: any, evnt: any) => void;
    getElementPos: (e: any) => number[];
    getElementSize: (e: any) => any[];
    getMousePos: (e: any) => any[];
    getViewPos: () => number[];
    getViewSize: () => number[];
    URI: (uri: any) => void;
    color: (target: any, prop: any) => void;
};
```

In the component, or wherever you need it reference that type definition file like this at the top of your file:

```
///<reference path="path/to/the/jscolor.d.ts"/>
```

---

> Alternatively you could look into
>   https://github.com/Alberplz/angular2-color-picker

Comment: I was looking at angular2-color-picker first but had some wierd problems. I added a issue but havent heard back yet.